# R if then else loop

Tags: r

I have the following output and would like to insert a column if net.results$net output equal to 0 if the output if <0.5 and 1 if >0.5 but <1.0.  Basically rounding up or down.

How do I go about doing in this in a loop ?  Can I insert this column using data.frame below , just in between the predicted and the test set columns ?

Assume I don't know the number of rows that net.results$net.result has.

Thank you for your help.

data.frame(net.results$net.result,diabTest$class)

```
           predicted col            Test set col

net.results.net.result diabTest.class
4             0.2900909633              0
7             0.2900909633              1
10            0.4912509122              1
12            0.4912509122              1
19            0.2900909633              0
21            0.2900909633              0
23            0.4912509122              1
26            0.2900909633              1
27            0.4912509122              1
33            0.2900909633              0
```

Comment: Please consider posting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)`. That would make this a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: And if it's greater than 1? Or equal to 1? Or equal to 0.5?

Comment: Based on the example showed, none of the elements in the first column (`net.results.net.result`) is `> 0.5`.

Comment: And if you're just rounding up or down, did you look at `round`?

Comment: If net.results$net.result <0.5 then 1,  if net.results$net.result between 0.5 and 1 then output 1.  Basically rounding up or down.   Don't worry about what the elements contain now.  It is just a binary classifier.

Comment: Unclearest question ever, -1 until editing. Please use `dput` function on your input `data.frame` and state clearly what you want to achieve, and it will get better!

Comment: @user4745212 did you mean `net.results$net.result <0.5` then 0?

Comment: @akrun, with the state of this question, I'm not going to make any assumptions about whether the data are ever larger than 1.

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yes, it is not clear.  My comment was based on `1 if >0.5 but <1.0`.  Possibly, the OP may not have have data larger than 1 as you said.

Comment: I need to do this in a loop.

Comment: @user4745212, you aren't answering the relevant questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out. This will not work for some situations, but based on the appearance of the data, this should produce the output desired.

```
df$rounded <- round(df$net.results.net.result,0)
```

Here are a few test values to see what the function does for different numbers. Read the `round` help page for more info.

```
round(0.2900909633,0)
[1] 0
round(0.51, 0)
[1] 1
```

You can help everyone by supplying a reproducible example, doing research, and explaining approaches that you've tried.

Comment: Thank you.  It works . the code is some neural network which I can't really post.

Comment: reproducible could mean something as simple as making a dummy table with 10 random decimals in one column and 10 random 1's and 0's in another. If you want to continue getting help, you have to supply more information, not necessarily your exact data source.